# How to fix left-aligned menu in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, tablet-pc

For the last couple of days, this is what my menus have looked like in Visual Studio 2010:

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio menu on Tools item]

How do I restore right-aligned menu items without losing any of my settings?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does so for me not only in Visual Studio but also in Notepad and other applications (well, not the ones the reinvented menus poorly).

There is a setting in the Tablet PC Settings to tell Windows which is your writing hand (so that menus won't appear underneath your hand). You can find it by searching for "hand write" in the start menu or go directly to the Tablet PC Settings:

[image: screenshot of Tablet PC Settings window]

Comment: Yes, also Notepad (but don't use that)

I can't believe that so many application are ignoring this settings.

Comment: @Albert: Many applications use various different toolkits. They only try to look similar to the native controls but this fails every now and then. Firefox with XUL gets it wrong, GTK gets it wrong as well and the Windows Forms MenuStrip control apparently too. WPF (which is what the VS2010 UI is written in) seems to get it right again.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution ....

Btw. no other application means ... Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

The Fix is easy, change

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\MenuDropAlignment

from 0 to 1 (REG_SZ)

In Detail here

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html

But i still don't know why it was set to 0.